# How to have a trigger work on insert and update?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssis

I have a trigger that I am trying to get to `update/insert` data to one specific column whenever an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` happens. Problem it only seems to work on `UPDATE`...

This is really the first trigger I have ever written and I cant quite figure it out. Can anyone help me with where I am going wrong?

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TEST_TRIGGER]
    ON  [dbo].[TEST_TABLE] 
    AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].TEST_TABLE
    SET HASH_VALUE = HASHBYTES('md5', 
        CAST(ISNULL([COL_1], -1) as nvarchar(255)) 
        + CAST(ISNULL([COL_2], -1) as nvarchar(255)) 
        + CAST(ISNULL([COL_3], -1) as nvarchar(255)) 
        + CAST(ISNULL([COL_4], -1) as nvarchar(255))
    )
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted)

END
GO
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with this - and in fact, I just tried this on SQL Server 2014 and it works just fine as far as I can see. How does your `INSERT` statement look like that doesn't seem to work for you?

Comment: @marc_s - Thank you for the comment. Turns out my trigger was completely fine. I added my answer at the bottom for anyone's future interest if you would like to see what i did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out...

I did not think at the time that it was relevant, but it turns out I was wrong. My initial issue was that I was `INSERT`ing data via SSIS. Apparently I needed to set a property in my `OLE DB Destination` to fire my `TRIGGERS`.

The way I did this was found from [here](https://try2fal.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/how-to-fire-triggers-during-an-insert-operation-with-ssis/).

It was not exactly cut and dry for me so here is a summary of what needs to be done:

1. Right click `OLE DB Destination` > `Show Advanced Editor`
2. Select `Component Properties` tab
3. Set `Access Mode` to `OpenRowset Using FastLoad`
4. Add `FIRE_TRIGGERS` in `FastLoadOptions`